# Don't Starve Together: How do I get an online server to work offline?

Tags: dont-starve-together

I created a don't starve together server online, but now I would like to play it offline with a friend. When I try to open it in offline mode it says, "You can only resume an online world when you have a connection to steam and klei. Please log in and try again." Is there a way to work around this and change the world to be offline somehow? I have access to the world file if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Answer from user115529 in the coments to this topic question:

> I found a solution: Open the saveindex file and change
>   "online_mode=true" to "online_mode=false". The only drawback is that
>   new characters will be created and items carried by previous
>   characters will be lost. If you plan to do this, make sure all
>   characters drop their stuff before changing the online mode.

In the oficial DST forum Developers give some hints about it : [Official DST forum: How to convert offline world to online](https://forums.kleientertainment.com/forums/topic/58487-how-to-convert-offline-world-to-online/)

The steps given by a user there are:

> 0) Go into your server and drop all your stuff to the ground.
>   1) Close DST.
>   2) Go to MyDocuments/Klei/DoNotStarveTogether/save.
>   3) Right click saveindex, open it with notepad.
>   4) Find your server among the table records (look at the name entries).
>   5) Under it, change online_mode from false to true.

Also, a developer says:

> Important! If you do this, everyone may lose their character. It would
>   be a good idea to run to the starting portal and drop all your stuff
>   on the ground first, so you can pick it up again when you come back in
>   after making the server online mode.

To avoid losing progress in some characters like wx with gear upgrades, or learned recipes, one possible solution can be to temporarily use the mod "Too many items", that lets you spawn any kind of game items. This way you can spawn recipes you had and items like gears to restore the character to its previous state: [Too many items mod](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=551338671)